# Showing and alerting logged errors from Rails app on Google App Engine / Stackdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

My Rails app is running in Google App Engine and I have the `stackdriver (0.15.3)` gem loaded.

In my Rails app, I call `Rails.logger.error "some message"` when there is a serious issue I need to know about.

This error appears in Stackdriver logs, categorised as an error.

But only when I'm displaying "Any log level". If I set it to only show 'Warns' and greater, it shows nothing.

Also, the log seems to be a child of the original GET request, and when the original GET request is hidden, so is the child error. Is there a way to show *all* errors when filtering is set to show errors?

Secondly, I'm using Google "Error Reporting" to send me alerts. It seems to only pick up Exceptions, and not any errors that are logged via `Rails.logger.error`. Is there a way to include these logged errors?

Comment: I believe you can use following filter as an [advanced filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) to include error. You should replace your project id and servicename in the following filter.                                                                                 **- resource.type="gae_app" 
resource.labels.module_id="SERVICE-NAME" 
logName="projects/PROJECT-ID/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log" 
protoPayload.line.severity="ERROR"**